# How do I get wider numpy array print output?

Tags: python, arrays, printing, numpy

It's word wrapping after 5 columns when there's enough space for all in one line.
For example:

```
print array
==========================restart=========================================
([32235, 2323424, 2342342
3525324, 234234])
([234234, 23423, 543535,
76572, 23424])
```

Using python Idle, and I tried changing the initial window size preferences. The restart bar extends all the way across but not the numpy array ouput.

Can't seem to find the answer after searching around either.
I'm sick and would really appreciate any help.
Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't replicate the issue (admittedly not using IDLE, which may be the issue). How is array defined?

Comment: It comes from a csv file turned into lists of lists and then into numpy array. I feel like the precision is set higher than the printarray usually allocates per cell. Numbers are about this long
5.22474679
5.18417234

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `np.vectorize`:

```
printer = np.vectorize(lambda x:'{0:5}'.format(x,))
print printer(b).astype(object)
```

Or try using `np.set_printoptions`:

Exactly as shown in IDLE:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x=np.random.random(10)
>>> x
array([ 0.72239823,  0.69938461,  0.85466846,  0.03294278,  0.06698482,
        0.04137562,  0.4223521 ,  0.81317235,  0.62221494,  0.6205595 ])
>>> np.set_printoptions(precision=3)
>>> print(x)
[ 0.722  0.699  0.855  0.033  0.067  0.041  0.422  0.813  0.622  0.621]
```

Comment: Yep! Thank you! Sorry for taking a while I crashed afterwards. It was a good workaround, and I'm surprised it had that basically default issue with little documentation. Hope you have a great weekend!

Answer (score 23):

The actual answer to your question, which does not require sacrificing precision, is the following:

```
 import numpy as np
 large_width = 400
 np.set_printoptions(linewidth=large_width)
```

Comment: Thank you from 2020~! I searched high and low for this and most answers were centred on increasing the width of the cell or widening the format, not increasing the number of columns in an array, which you have masterfully resolved.